# Angular 5 how to wait for styles.css is loaded

Tags: html, css, angular

I am making an angular application and I need to preload some data. So for that, the user will see a loading page until the data is loaded.

But my problem is that the styles from the styless.css file is not yet loaded if the page is loaded. The file is only loaded after 1 sec. The means that the user will first see this:

[image: No css]

Only after the file is loaded, the user will see this:

[image: with css]

My question: how can i wait for the styles.css file to be loaded?

html code:

```
.saving {
   text-align: center;
   position: absolute;
   font-size: 35px;
   width: 250px;
   height: 70px;
   line-height: 50px;
   text-align: center;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-weight: 900;
   letter-spacing: 0.2em;
 }

 .saving span {
   font-size: 50px;
   animation-name: blink;
   animation-duration: 1.4s;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   animation-fill-mode: both;
 }

 .saving span:nth-child(2) {
   animation-delay: .2s;
 }

 .saving span:nth-child(3) {
   animation-delay: .4s;
 }

 @keyframes blink {
   0% {
     opacity: .2;
   }
   20% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   100% {
     opacity: .2;
   }
 }
```

html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Root</title>
  <base href="/" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" 
rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  <root-page></root-page>


<div>
  <p class="saving">Loading<span>.</span><span>.</span><span>.</span></p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the css needed for the page load animation in the `index.html` in a `<style>` tag. (so copy-paste the "saving" class)

Or, if you really need to reference the whole css, reference from the assets it in the `index.html` with a `<script src="...">` tag.

Comment: Stupid mistake. Thought that I already referenced the file somewhere. Thanks